# problems with trivial number conversions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers, type-conversion, ghci

I am attempting to write a trivial function to drop the last digit of a number and return the rest of the number.

```
dropLastDigit :: (Integral b) => b -> b
dropLastDigit x = (quot x 10) * (floor $ logBase 10 x)
```

however, when I try to load this into ghci, I get:

```
Could not deduce (Floating b) arising from a use of ‘logBase’
    from the context (Integral b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 dropLastDigit :: Integral b => b -> b
      at haskelljokes.hs:6:18-39
    Possible fix:
      add (Floating b) to the context of
        the type signature for dropLastDigit :: Integral b => b -> b
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘logBase 10 x’
    In the expression: floor $ logBase 10 x
    In an equation for ‘dropLastDigit’:
        dropLastDigit x = floor $ logBase 10 x
```

However, running this code in ghci:

`:t (quot 101 10) * (floor $ logBase 10 101)`

produces: `(quot 101 10) * (floor $ logBase 10 101) :: Integral a => a`

My question is, what am I doing wrong? And why is (the identical code?) working in ghci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not identical. You can check this easily:

```
ghci> let value101 = 101 :: Integral b => b
ghci> let value10  = 10  :: Integral b => b
ghci> (quot value101 value10) * (floor $ logBase value10 value101)

<interactive>:7:28:
    Could not deduce (RealFrac s0) arising from a use of `floor'
    from the context (Integral a)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral a => a
      at <interactive>:7:1-60
    The type variable `s0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => RealFrac (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
    In the expression: floor
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely
      `(floor $ logBase value10 value101)'
    In the expression:
      (quot value101 value10) * (floor $ logBase value10 value101)

-- even more...
```

The problem is that both `10` and `101` have type `Num a => a`, regardless of where you use them. So `logBase 10 101` used them with the default `Fractional` instance (`Double`), whereas `quot` used them with the default `Integral` instance.

That being said, your function doesn't "drop" the last digit. If you just want to transform `12345` to `1234`, you can simplify `dropLastDigit` to

```
dropLastDigit x = x `div` 10
```

If you, however, want to transform `12345` to `12340`, you just have to multiply by ten afterwards:

```
dropLastDigit x = 10 * (x `div` 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your function to

```
dropLastDigit :: (Integral b) => b -> b
dropLastDigit x = (quot x 10) * (floor $ logBase 10 (fromIntegral x))
```

The code you're running in GHCi is not identical. You've replaced `x` by `101`. The `x` in your function was annotated (by type signature) to be of type `b` for any type `b` in the `Integral` class, but `logBase` needs something in the `Floating` class.

On the other hand, the literal `101` is of type `Num a => a`, i.e., it is overloaded and can be used at any numeric type. So GHCi can use it at type `Integer` on the first occurrence, as an argument of `quot`, and as a `Double` on the second occurrence, as an argument to `logBase`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response. Really helps remind me to think through my typeclasses. Upvoted. Zeta beat you to it, so he gets the accept.