# Why can't I replace ^2 with sqrt in an inequality for takeWhile?

Tags: haskell

The following predicate correctly returns all numbers whose square is less than `i`:

```
takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= i) [1..10]
```

However, if I use `sqrt` on both sides, it doesn't work anymore:

```
takeWhile (\p -> p <= sqrt i) [1..10]
```

Why does this happen? And how can I fix this?

Comment: The first function has type `(Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool` while the second has type `(Ord a, Floating a) => a -> Bool`. This is because you can square any number (integer or real) but you can only compute the square root of a real. It isn't clear what the "problem" is - these are two valid, different functions, defined on different domains.

Comment: yes, but I wrote a function which generate primes and it works like it primes = 2 : [i | i <- [3..],  
              and [mod i p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p->p^2<=i) primes]] but I have a requirement to use sqrt and I don't know how to replace it in this context

Comment: Your numbers are integers, so you have to convert them to reals: `\p -> fromIntegral p <= sqrt (fromIntegral i)`.

Comment: Same reason as [yesterdays question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619011/problems-with-trivial-number-conversions-in-haskell).

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. If you are getting an error, include the error.

Comment: @Alice, an equivalent way to write it that works for integers is `\p -> p * p < i`.